# aframe/threejs camera manual rotation

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to manually tween camera rotation to 0,0:

```
camera.object3D.matrixAutoUpdate=false; 

var orgrot = { x : camera.object3D.rotation.x, y: camera.object3D.rotation.y };
var target = { x : 0, y: 0 };

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(orgrot).to(target, 500);
tween.onUpdate(function(){
          camera.object3D.rotation.x= this.x;
          camera.object3D.rotation.y= this.y;
          camera.object3D.updateMatrix();

  });
```

The tween works as expected, but I am loosing mouse control over camera.
To get it back I am setting matrixAutoUpdate to true

```
tween.onComplete(function(){
     document.querySelector('#camera').object3D.matrixAutoUpdate=true
});
```

But after that, the camera rotation changes back to original position (before tween ) and I would like to keep 0,0. What I am missing ? thanks

**UPDATE Below is a version using aframe only without going into threejs objects**

I think the problem is camera look-control component

When enabled - I can not animate camera rotation or even setAttribute.
I have to disable it first - than fire animation and than enable it again.

But the problem is, when I enable it again:

```
camera.setAttribute ('look-controls-enabled',"true")
```

camera goes back to original rotation ( state before reset animation ).
Similar problem when using `matrixAutoUpdate=false/true`

Here is my pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMjrWd

If you rotate left 30deg, it will fire resetCamera animation - it works as intended.
But only when look component is disabled. If I enable it again in "animationend" event - the rotation will go back to original state and trigger resetCamera again and again

Answer (score 0):

You really should not have to mess with `matrixAutoUpdate`.

But given that you are, try the following to force the `position`, `quaternion`, and `scale` to match the `matrix`:

```
object.matrix.decompose( object.position, object.quaternion, object.scale );
```

three.js r.76

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems. If you are using aframe you should not access the object3D directly. You should do

`cameraEl.setAttribute('position', {x: 0, y: 0; z;0 })`

You can apply a tween to any entity using [the declarative API](https://aframe.io/docs/core/animations.html)

If you want to modify the camera independently of the running tween you can wrap your camera in another entity

`<a-entity rotation="0 360 0"><a-entity id="camera" camera><a-animation ...></a-animation></a-entity></a-entity>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about wrapping camera in another entity.
That would probably work - but it makes calculation a bit more complex so I wonder if it can be solved on camera level.

I updated my post with codepen to show the problem

Comment: @KChris I have the same problem. I can't reset the rotation of the original camera. In order to do so, I have to wrap a parent element around the camera and do some calculations. (And sometimes I can't do them because then the rotation messes up.)

Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this codeblock, it works for me on aframe 0.8.2

```
static faceCameraToCoords(camera, coords){
    camera.setAttribute("look-controls",{enabled:false})
    camera.setAttribute("rotation", coords);
    var newX = camera.object3D.rotation.x
    var newY = camera.object3D.rotation.y
    camera.components['look-controls'].pitchObject.rotation.x = newX
    camera.components['look-controls'].yawObject.rotation.y = newY
    camera.setAttribute("look-controls",{enabled:true})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer set `a-camera` rotation after version 0.8.0.

**Updated solution for Aframe 0.9.2:**

Given the following camera setup:

```
<a-entity
  id="rig"
  position="0 1.6 0">
  <a-camera position="0 0 0"></a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

You can directly alter the camera rotation thus:

```
const cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-camera');
cameraEl.components['look-controls'].pitchObject.rotation.x = newRotation.x;
cameraEl.components['look-controls'].yawObject.rotation.y = newRotation.y;
```

Make sure the newRotation values are in radians. For example, use `THREE.Math.degToRad(newRotation.x)`.